# Use base class interface in templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm supposed to use base-class as a caller:

```cpp
void use(Base& b)
{
    int i = b.size();
    b.create();
}
void do()
{
    Subclass sub{5};
    use(sub);
}
```

But why shouldn't I use templates to eliminate run-time overhead:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void use(T& sub)
{
    int i = sub.size();
    sub.create();
}
void do()
{
    Subclass sub{5};
    use(sub);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* use this as an *optimization*. The compiler may perform *devirtualization* on its own if it sees fit. Use what's appropriated in your code.

That said, nothing prevents you to do that. It may or may not apply to your needs.

For example, if `use` is a virtual function or a function you need to store the object somewhere with a fixed type, you cannot use the template version of it.

If there is already virtual functions around, it may have very little gain as templates have their own downside.

Also, unless the virtual function is marked as `final`, it wont necessarily remove the virtual call. This is because another class may inherit from the one you are sending and will have to call the function from the virtual table.